# how to create private web server running in a personal pc

Tags: php, mysql, web

I would like to practice web design by myself. I have not had any problem at the moment to practice css, javascript and html. The problem starts when I try to practice PHP and SQL, to do this i believe that a server is necessary. I would like to know if there is any way to create a local loop or private server that can simulate a server to test my private web page?

To give further information my pc runs on windows, for this I would have predilection to make this server without the need of installing a virtual machine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP is the most common package for this.
http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1 Just download and install wampserver http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

2 Make sure you do not install it in your "Program Files" directory. You could use the C:\wamp

3 Put all your files in installationDirectory/www

That's all you need